# Sum of two statistically independent (uncorrelated) functions

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, independence, correlation

I want to calculate the Cross-Correlation of two statistically independent (uncorrelated) functions
$$
X_{1}(t)=X(t) + V_{1}(t)
$$
$$
X_{2}(t)=X(t-T_{L}) + V_{2}(t)
$$
where
$$
E[V_{1}(t).V_{2}(t)]=E[V_{1}(t)].E[V_{2}(t)]
$$
and
$$
E[V_{1}(t).V_{2}(t).X(t)]=E[V_{1}(t)].E[V_{2}(t)].E[X(t)]
$$

The question is, if the sum in $X_{1}(t)$ and $X_{2}(t)$ returns a uncorrelated function.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The autocorrelation of X would cause a correlation between X1 and X2 I think

Comment: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are also uncorrelated to each other. Does that mean that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also uncorrelated?

Comment: The point @Thomas is making is (I think) that if $X(t)$ and $X(t-T_L)$ are (auto)correlated then $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$ will be correlated, presumably with the same covariance

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I meant. The fact that V1 an V2 are uncorrelated between each other should not "remove" this dependence due to the autocorrelation of X, if this is what you mean, Tom.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks!